# Displacement map to approximate details in dynamic topology sculpt

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting, displacement

I've started using a tool called retopoflow by cgcookie to create low-poly mesh that snaps to the surface of the high-poly sculpt. In one of the tutorial videos, they mention that they aren't going for tons of detail because "[you'd use a displacement modifier for that]". So, if you have a high-poly sculpt and a low-poly re-topology, how would you go about generating such a displacement map?

**Edit**

Here's a screen shot. As you can see, the re-topo mesh is much less detailed than the sculpt. The narrator says that he would bring in a displacement map for the details left out in the re-topology.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: don't you think that a link to this video **indicating the timelaps** may be useful ?

Comment: Access to the video came with with the purchase. I'll add a screenshot and an edit.

Comment: You are looking for "Baking displacement map". The displaced result of the lowpoly won't be the same as the high-poly though, especially on sharp edges.Blender doesn't offer vector displacement yet. Btw. for not much more money you should have bought Topogun.